# Chef-client IP address

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, configuration-management

Imagine, you have 3 machines - 1 chef-workstation, chef-server and 1 client which is configured.

So, I need to extract client's IP-address from configfiles/processes/etc on a chef-server or vice versa:
extract server's IP-address on chef-client machine(node).
(that means, that I can't use workstation for extracting IP-address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the chef workstation, get the nodes ipaddress with knife:

`knife search node '*' -a ipaddress`

And get the chef server ip by resolving its host name with dns, getting the chef server hostname from the knife.rb file eventually...

I don't get the point of tagging your question with ruby if you don't want to use it...

Answer (score 0):

From inside the template code on the client you can use `<%= node['ipaddress'] %>` to get the IP address of the default interface. Not sure what you mean by "on a chef-server".

Comment: I am writing a support product for chef. And I need to extract server's(or client's) IP adress from somewhere. I can't use any ruby coding. Only configfiles or just other UNIX utilities(like top)

Comment: From the client machine, you can use ohai directly by running `ohai ipaddress`. If you want to query the server, you can use any of a number of client libraries like [chef-api](https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-api) or [PyChef](https://github.com/coderanger/pychef/). It is possible to [query the Chef server using cURL](https://docs.getchef.com/auth.html#curl) but I really don't recommend it.